# CakePHP naming convention - one table depends on itself (mysql)

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, relational-database

I have a staff table (one staff can manage many staff whereas one staff can be supervised by many staff as well). I'm using CakePHP Bake All command so I have to stick to the naming convention of CakePHP in MySQL tables. I'm creating another table called "staff_staff", in which I should have one PK id, two FKs staff_id and staff_id according to CakePHP naming convention. How do I name the FK?

Comment: Have you read [**Cookbook > Multiple relations to the same model**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#multiple-relations-to-the-same-model)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#multiple-relations-to-the-same-model

This helps!

CustomFields Model has two hasAndBelongstoMany variable